# Getting the right interval on the x-axis in IOS-Charts

Tags: swift, ios-charts

I am trying to exclusively display the points which I have data for on the x-axis. As shown in the example below, I only got data for point zero, but -1 and 1 are being displayed as well. How can I get rid of them?

[image]

```
  func setChart(_ xValues: [String], yValuesLineChart: [Double], yValuesBarChart: [Double]) {


    var yVals1 : [ChartDataEntry] = [ChartDataEntry]()
    var yVals2 : [BarChartDataEntry] = [BarChartDataEntry]()


    for i in 0..<xValues.count {
        yVals1.append(ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: yValuesLineChart[i]))
        yVals2.append(BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: yValuesBarChart[i]))
    }


    let lineChartSet = LineChartDataSet(values: yVals1, label: "")
    let barChartSet: BarChartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(values: yVals2, label: "")

    combinedChartView.drawBarShadowEnabled = false

    let data = CombinedChartData()

    data.barData = BarChartData(dataSet: barChartSet)
    data.lineData = LineChartData(dataSet: lineChartSet)


    combinedChartView.xAxis.granularityEnabled = true
    combinedChartView.xAxis.granularity = 1.0
    combinedChartView.xAxis.decimals = 0


    combinedChartView.leftAxis.axisMinimum = 0
    combinedChartView.rightAxis.axisMinimum = 0


    combinedChartView.chartDescription?.text = ""
    combinedChartView.drawGridBackgroundEnabled = false

    combinedChartView.xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom

    combinedChartView.leftAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
    combinedChartView.rightAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
    combinedChartView.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false


    combinedChartView.leftAxis.drawZeroLineEnabled = false
    combinedChartView.rightAxis.drawZeroLineEnabled = false


    barChartSet.axisDependency = .right
    lineChartSet.axisDependency = .left


    combinedChartView.rightAxis.axisMaximum = barChartSet.yMax*1.4
    combinedChartView.leftAxis.axisMaximum = lineChartSet.yMax*1.2


    combinedChartView.data = data
    combinedChartView.animate(xAxisDuration: 2.0, yAxisDuration: 2.0, easingOption: .easeInCubic)


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write an extension for your ViewController that will just display an empty string if you have no value.

```
extension YourChartViewController:IAxisValueFormatter {
    func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String {
        if value == 0.0
            return ""
        } else {
            return String(Int(value))
        }
    }
}
```